# Save <svg> HTML5 to PNG or image

Tags: html, svg, export

I have got charts generated with D3 Javascript library and i need to save these to file PNG or SVG.

Is there some library that makes the job?

I found this https://github.com/sampumon/SVG.toDataURL but is not working on my html5,
in firefox console i got this error:

NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component is not available
[Interrompi per questo errore]

ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

Comment: Here is an example on how to do it with Chrome: http://bl.ocks.org/3831266

Comment: thanks! this is working...but when i try to open the file in illustrator it asks me to validate the file.I have this message: this svg is invalid. Validate before open.

Comment: Find an XML validator and make sure it's valid XML. If everything seems ok, then post the code in your question and I can help you find the error that is causing Illustrator to trip.

Comment: Also, make sure you include the XML namespace in the svg tag, such as... `d3.select('svg').attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");`

Answer (score 9):

Example from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas) demonstrating how to export svg to png using canvas element.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
           '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
           '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
             '<em>I</em> like ' + 
             '<span style="color:white; text-shadow:0 0 2px blue;">' +
             'cheese</span>' +
           '</div>' +
           '</foreignObject>' +
           '</svg>';

var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  var png_img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}

img.src = url;
```

Comment: couldn't use using by selecting a <svg> element on the inspector

Comment: Woohoo! That worked.

Answer (score 2):

This extension works with all `<svg>` tags in the page: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/svg-export/naeaaedieihlkmdajjefioajbbdbdjgp?hl=en-GB

Comment: This extension is great and very easy to use. With one click you are shown with a UI of all available SVGs on that page and can export with any dimensions you want.

Answer (score 1):

## Server-side script method

Here is a simple method to save svg elements to png(though it uses server-side scripting, which may be different from what you'd expect):
Checkout [this page](http://d3export.cancan.cshl.edu/).

As is documented by the author, the client extract the svg element (using XMLSerializer.serializeToString)and send it to server; the server convert it to png and send it back to the client. The server can use any program that is convenient(rsvg-convert in this case).

## Canvg library

You can use this library to do this on client side [(check it out!)](https://code.google.com/p/canvg/):

> canvg is a SVG parser and renderer. It takes a URL to a SVG file or the text of an SVG file, parses it in JavaScript, and renders the result on a Canvas element

Use it like this:

```
//load a svg snippet in the canvas with id = 'drawingArea'
canvg(document.getElementById('drawingArea'), '<svg>... </svg>')
```

Then you can use the toDataURL method:
`document.getElementById('drawingArea').toDataURL('image/png');`